# Final PDF include table of contents "\thesection" prefixes

Tags: table-of-contents

when im solving a list of exercises i tend to modify \thesection like this:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{Questão \arabic{section}}
```

I want to have these on my final PDF toc, not the one who is printed in the first page, but the one who is read by the pdf reader.

Here a simple demonstration of the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Clickable Table of contents
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% Table of contents
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{25mm}       % Fix section width
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{12mm}
% Fix space between subsection items on toc
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip5pt}

% Multicols
\usepackage{multicol}

% Maths
\usepackage{amssymb}        
\usepackage{amsmath} 

% Section, Subsection and subsubsection Customization
\renewcommand\thesection{Questão \arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{%
    \arabic{section} - \alph{subsection})%
}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{(\roman{subsubsection})}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents

\break

% Q1
\section{}

\begin{multicols}{2}

% Q1 (i)
\subsubsection{$\alpha$}
\begin{flalign*}
&
=   2\,\beta + \theta
&
\end{flalign*}

% Q1 (ii)
\subsubsection{$\beta$}
\begin{flalign*}
&
=   1+3
&
\end{flalign*}

\end{multicols}

\break

% Q2
\section{}

% Q2 - a)
\subsection{}
\begin{flalign*}
&
    \text{random calculations}\cdots
&
\end{flalign*}

% Q2 - b)
\subsection{Pie}
\begin{flalign*}
&
=   \pi
&
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

The resulting table of contents of the code above gives:

[image]

Where i want in the blue area of the image above to be read: "Questão 1"

**The solution as provided by Simon Dispa:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}



% Linguagem
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}  % Babel



% Table of contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    % remove subsubsection from toc



% Multicols
\usepackage{multicol}



% Maths
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}



% hyperref
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}



% Solutuion by Simon Dispa =====================>



% questions, subquestions and subsubquestions

% question
\newcounter{question}[section]
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{Questão \arabic{question}}
\newcommand{\question}[1]{
     % reset inner counters
     \setcounter{subquestion}{0}
     \setcounter{subsubquestion}{0}
     % add section*
     \refstepcounter{question}
     \section*{\thequestion\quad#1}
     % add to toc
     \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
        \thequestion\quad#1%
    }
}

% subquestion
\newcounter{subquestion}[subsection]
\renewcommand\thesubquestion{%
    Q\arabic{question} - \alph{subquestion})%
}
\newcommand{\subquestion}[1]{
    % reset inner counters
    \setcounter{subsubquestion}{0}
    % add subsection*
     \refstepcounter{subquestion}
     \subsection*{\thesubquestion\quad#1}
     % add to toc
     \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{%
        \thesubquestion\quad#1%
    }
}

% subsubquestion
\newcounter{subsubquestion}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand{\thesubsubquestion}{(\roman{subsubquestion})}
\newcommand{\subsubquestion}[1]{
    % add subsubsection*
     \refstepcounter{subsubquestion}
     \subsubsection*{\thesubsubquestion\quad#1}
     % add to toc
     \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{%
        \thesubsubquestion\quad#1%
    }
}



% Solutuion by Simon Dispa =====================>



\begin{document}



\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents



\break



% Q1
\question{}

\begin{multicols}{2}


% Q1 (i)
\subsubquestion{$\alpha$}
\begin{flalign*}
&
=   2\,\beta + \theta
&
\end{flalign*}


% Q1 (ii)
\subsubquestion{$\beta$}
\begin{flalign*}
&
=   1+3
&
\end{flalign*}


\end{multicols}



\newpage



% Q2
\question{}


% Q2 - a)
\subquestion{}
\begin{flalign*}
&
    \text{random calculations}\cdots
&
\end{flalign*}


% Q2 - b)
\subquestion{}

% Q2 - b) (i)
\subsubquestion{Pie}
\begin{flalign*}
&
=   \pi
&
\end{flalign*}



\newpage



% Q3
\question{}

% Q3 - a)
\subquestion{}

% Q3 - b)
\subquestion{}

% Q3 - c)
\subquestion{}

\newpage

% Q4
\question{}

\begin{multicols}{2}


% Q4 (i)
\subsubquestion{$\alpha$}
\begin{flalign*}
&
    E = mc
&
\end{flalign*}


% Q4 (ii)
\subsubquestion{$\beta$}
\begin{flalign*}
&
   E = mc^2
&
\end{flalign*}


% Q4 (iii)
\subsubquestion{$\gamma$}
\begin{flalign*}
&
    E = mc^3
&
\end{flalign*}


% Q4 (iv)
\subsubquestion{$\delta$}
\begin{flalign*}
&
    E = mc^4
&
\end{flalign*}


\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

Resulting in the following output:
[image]

Thanks in advance

- Edit 1: Adding MWE as requested by Peter Wilson
- Edit 2: Adding solution by Simon Dispa

Comment: Please provide and MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can process that shows what you have done and what your problem is.

Comment: There you go...

Comment: Possibly related (probably not): with few exceptions, hyperref should be the last package loaded.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that, i never know what order to load the packages, thankfully so far loading hyperref first never failed me, imma fix my templates now before it starts giving me problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of re-defining `\section` , `\subsection` , etc. I defined three new commands with their own counters.

`\question` that behaves like a `\section*{}` typesets `Questão <question number>` and adds a section entry to the TOC.

`\option` behaves like `\subsection{}` typesets `<question number> - < option number>)`  and adds a subsection entry to the TOC.

`\optionM{optitle}`  behaves like `\subsubsection{title}` and typesets  `(optionM number) optitle`.

`\option` and `\optionM` work also in two columns mode. They must be used after a `\question`.

The bookmarks in the pdf are created by the package `bookmark`.

The `hyperref` can also be used but I found `bookmark` easier to setup.
Option #2: `\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2,hidelinks]{hyperref}`

**Your question**

[image: a]

[image: t]

[image: z]

This is the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


% Table of contents
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{25mm}       % Fix section width
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{12mm}
% Fix space between subsection items on toc
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip5pt}

% Multicols
\usepackage{multicol}

% Maths
\usepackage{amssymb}        
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\newcounter{question}[section]
\newcommand{\question}{% starts a question numbered sequentially
    \setcounter{option}{0} % reset inner counters
    \setcounter{optionM}{0}
    \refstepcounter{question}%
    \section*{Questão \thequestion}% 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Questão \thequestion}% add section* to toc
}

\newcounter{option}[subsection]
\newcommand{\option}{%
    \refstepcounter{option}%
    \subsection*{\thequestion-\alph{option})}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\thequestion-\alph{option}}%
}

\newcounter{optionM}[subsubsection]
\newcommand{\optionM}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{optionM}%
    \subsubsection*{(\roman{optionM}) #1}%
%   \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\thequestion (\alph{optionM})}% optional for \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} <<<<
}

% Clickable Table of contents 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}% option #1
\usepackage[open]{bookmark}% option #1

%\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2,hidelinks]{hyperref} % option #2

\begin{document}
    
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents    
\newpage

% Q1
\question

\begin{multicols}{2}

% Q1 (i)
\optionM{$\alpha$}
\begin{flalign*}
&
=   2\,\beta + \theta
&
\end{flalign*}

% Q1 (ii)
\optionM{$\beta$}
\begin{flalign*}
&
=   1+3
&
\end{flalign*}

\end{multicols}

%\newpage

% Q2
\question   
% Q2 - a)
\option
\begin{flalign*}
&
\text{random calculations}\cdots
&
\end{flalign*}

\option % Q2 - b)
%   \subsection{Pie}
\begin{flalign*}
&
=   \pi
&
\end{flalign*}

%\newpage

\question %Q3

\option % Q3 - a)

\option % Q3 - b)

\option % Q3 - c)

%\newpage

% Q4
\question

\begin{multicols}{2}    
    % Q4 (i)
    \optionM{$\alpha$}
    \begin{flalign*}
        &
    E   =   mc
        &
    \end{flalign*}
    
    % Q4 (ii)
    \optionM{$\beta$}
        \begin{flalign*}
        &
        E   =   mc^2
        &
    \end{flalign*}
    
        % Q4 (iii)
    \optionM{$\gamma$}
        \begin{flalign*}
        &
        E   =   mc^3
        &
    \end{flalign*}
    
    % Q4 (iv)
    \optionM{$\delta$}
        \begin{flalign*}
        &
        E   =   mc^4
        &
    \end{flalign*}  
\end{multicols}
    
\end{document}
```

**Note** If you want `\optionM` to behave like `\option`, appearing in the TOC and in the bookmarks, use

```
\newcounter{optionM}[subsection]
\newcommand{\optionM}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{optionM}%
\subsection*{(\roman{optionM}) #1}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\thequestion (\alph{optionM})}
}
```

[image: w]

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks Simon.